# Nginx, default server block cannot see php files - but sub domain can

Tags: php, nginx, server, block

I'm not great with Nginx yet, so I would really appreciate a little bit of help here.

Now my problem is, my default server block domain.com, has all `php` files denied access to them.

At `www.domain.com/index.php` I get the correct 403 Forbidden page shown.

But if I head to `www.SomeRandomSubDomain.domain.com/index.php` I can see the file just fine.
I don't have any other server blocks. Am I missing a little tag of some sort in my first line below?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            deny all;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in
            # php.ini
            # With php5-cgi alone: fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            #include fastcgi_params;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

Please let me know if you need any other information to further assist me, this has kind of left me in a world of confusion, I didn't get lucky with Google.

**Here's the full file:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name EXAMPLE.com www.EXAMPLE.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location include
            # /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
            }
    location ~ .(css|img)/(.+)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2;
    }

    error_page 404 403 /404.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            deny all;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in
            # php.ini
            # With php5-cgi alone: fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            #include fastcgi_params;
            include fastcgi.conf;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to remove `deny all;` from php configuration

Comment: Removing deny all; will only allow it to display php files.